# Can't figure why I can't append data to end of ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, cursor

I am using the add() to append data to my ArrayList but I believe the logic of my cursor is making the data I am trying to append actually go through and replace all my Arraylist data instead.

here is the method from my DBHandler.java

```
public ArrayList databaseToStringDate(){

    String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());

    ArrayList<String> dateList = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + KICK_TABLE + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
            dateList.add(dateString);
           // dateString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    db.close();
    return dateList;
}
```

and here is the code from my fragment class that displays the textView which is working fine

```
 ArrayList dbDate = dbHandler.databaseToStringDate();

    String dbDateString = dbDate.toString();

    date.setText( dbDateString);
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What does your ArrayList contain? What do you think it should contain?

Comment: I want to display the date of when the user does a certain task but the date for everything gets the last date. For example I have "2017-07-18" In a TextView and if the user does said action tommarow I want "2017-07-18, 2017-07-19". But I am getting  "2017-07-19, 2017-07-19" instead.

Comment: Does your table have a column that contains the date value?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your code, you define `dateString` as

```
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
```

You retrieve the rows from your database and for each row in your database, you call

```
dateList.add(dateString);
```

But you never reassigned `dateString` to represent the date in the row from the database. You need to read out the date column from your database and parse add *that* `String` to your `ArrayList`. For example:

```
while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
        dateList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")));
    }
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Without that extra column lookup, you're just adding the same `String` to the `ArrayList` over and over.